# RandomForestClassifier Explainer Dashboard output in databricks notebook is not rendered

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, databricks

I am trying to render RandomForestClassifier model dashboard using ExplainerDashboard package, but it is not rendering the dashboard in notebook.

Here is the code

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, max_depth=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test) 
ExplainerDashboard(explainer).run()
```

I was getting below output

```
=========================================================================

Detected RandomForestClassifier model: Changing class type to RandomForestClassifierExplainer...

Note: model_output=='probability', so assuming that raw shap output of RandomForestClassifier is in probability space...

Generating self.shap_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
Building ExplainerDashboard..

Detected notebook environment, consider setting mode='external', mode='inline' or mode='jupyterlab' to keep the notebook interactive while the dashboard is running...

Warning: calculating shap interaction values can be slow! Pass shap_interaction=False to remove interactions tab.

Generating layout...

Calculating shap values...

Calculating prediction probabilities...

Calculating metrics...

Calculating confusion matrices...

Calculating classification_dfs...

Calculating roc auc curves...

Calculating pr auc curves...

Calculating liftcurve_dfs...

Calculating shap interaction values... (this may take a while)

Reminder: TreeShap computational complexity is O(TLD^2), where T is the number of trees, L is the maximum number of leaves in any tree and D the maximal depth of any tree. So reducing these will speed up the calculation.

Calculating dependencies...

Calculating permutation importances (if slow, try setting n_jobs parameter)...

Calculating pred_percentiles...

Calculating predictions...

Calculating ShadowDecTree for each individual decision tree...

Reminder: you can store the explainer (including calculated dependencies) with explainer.dump('explainer.joblib') and reload with e.g. ClassifierExplainer.from_file('explainer.joblib')

Registering callbacks...

Starting ExplainerDashboard on http://19.221.249.249:8055

Dash is running on http://0.0.0.0:8055/


 * Serving Flask app 'explainerdashboard.dashboards' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://19.221.249.249:8055/

=========================================================================
```

But dashboard is not rendered in notebook. I tried with InlineExplainer also, it was returning <IPython.lib.display.IFrame at 0x7f4eea3e1c70>

Can you please suggest any idea to render dashboard in databricks notebook

Answer (score 0):

To render the dashboard in your notebook, you should use the [InlineExplainer](https://explainerdashboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#inlineexplainer).
With that, you can plot model performance or shape values for instance as explained in the [documentation](https://explainerdashboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/inline.html).

You can use the following code as a reference:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from explainerdashboard.datasets import titanic_survive
from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard
from explainerdashboard import InlineExplainer

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, max_depth=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test) 

InlineExplainer(explainer).shap.overview()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps you will be able to get the ExplainerDashboard view:

Step 1) Set the Environment variables in Databricks Cluster

For example :

DASH_REQUEST_PATHNAME_PREFIX=/driver-proxy/o/40xxxxxxxx/1004xxxxx/8888

Workspace ID : 40xxxxxxx
Cluster-ID: 1004xxxxxxxx
Port number: 8888

Step 2) Install the explainerdashboard library

%pip install explainerdashboard

Step 3) Sample code to validate the "dash"

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard

from explainerdashboard.datasets import titanic_survive, feature_descriptions

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, max_depth=10).fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test,

cats=['Deck', 'Embarked'],

descriptions=feature_descriptions,

labels=['Not survived', 'Survived'])

**ExplainerDashboard(explainer, mode = 'dash',**

importances=False,

model_summary=False,

contributions=True,

whatif=False,

shap_dependence=False,

shap_interaction=False,

**decision_trees=False).run(8888)**

Step 4) Dashboard URL

https://xxxxxxxx.databricks.com/driver-proxy/o/<workspaceID/clusterID/8888

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).